# How to develop this layout in AngularJS and/or AngularJS Material?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I have following code:

```
div
    div Test1
    div(flex)
    div 12
    div(ng-show=“someCondition”, class="triangleLeft")
```

If the triangle is shown, it will push the `12` to the left. Is it able to hide/show the triangle without pushing the `12` to the left using AngularJS and/or AngularJS Material?

Here is my [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/iUvKFT6LjkmWo3CHAEIW) :)

Comment: Can you post a runnable snippet or a plunker? That would really help

Comment: Here it goes. Please help to check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/iUvKFT6LjkmWo3CHAEIW?p=preview) is a forked version of your plunk

The parent `div` should be relatively positioned like this

```
position: relative;
```

The `triangle` or the `chevron` must be absolutely positioned and should be placed at `right: 0px` like this

```
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
```

Now you can see that the triangle does not push the text `12`to the left. But you can see that it hides the text. You could add a right/left padding to the parent div like below so it looks better

```
 padding: 0 10px;
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed to make the parent div's position to relative.